# How do I check if a character in a string is a non-letter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, char, letter

So the code I'm writing is intended to replace all the vowels with alternate letters, and then return "Error" if any character in a particular string is a non letter. I got the first part to work but how do I check for a non letter?

```
def signature(name):
    names = name
    for n in name:
        if n == "a":
             names = names.replace(n,'b')
        if n == 'e':
             names = names.replace(n, 'f')
        if n == 'i':
             names = names.replace(n,'j')
        if n == 'o':
             names = names.replace(n, 'p')
        if n == 'u':
             names = names.replace(n,'v')

    return names
```

Comment: You're looking for [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

Comment: You're also looking for [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) :^)

Answer (score 3):

As Paul suggests, use `isalpha` to check if a string contains only letters:

```
assert name.isalpha()
```

Using `assert` in this way will raise an error if the name contains a non alphabet character.

Your vowel conversion can be simplified:

```
def replace(c):
    if c in 'aeoui':
        return chr(ord(c) + 1)
    return c # return c if not a vowel

name = "".join([replace(c) for c in name])
```

- Use `ord` to convert the character to an integer
- Increment this by one
- Use `chr` to build a character back from the integer